# Error in x86 assembly using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86

I get a stack overflow exception when running this piece of code. This is a short example of the real program in which I use local variables. The problem comes when doing this instruction: mov ebx, [edi + 4 * ebx].  Can anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int n = 9;


int main()
{
    unsigned int* v = new unsigned int[n];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v[i] = i;
    }

    __asm
    {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        sub esp, 8                  // We reserve the corresponding space for 6 local variables

        mov edi, v                  // We move the vector v into edi

        mov eax, 0                  // We store into eax the position 0
        mov ebx, 0                  // We store into ebx the position 1
        mov eax, [ebp - 4]          // We move into eax the current position of the vector
        mov ebx, [ebp - 8]          // We move into ebx the proper jump in order to compare both positions
        add ebx, eax                // We add to eax the required jump
        mov ebx, [edi + 4 * ebx]    // We move into ebx the value of the position in ebx
        mov eax, [edi + 4 * eax]    // We move into eax the value of the position in eax
        cmp eax, ebx                // We compare both values and...

        mov esp, ebp                // We restore the base pointer
        pop ebp
    }
}
```

Comment: You are reading an uninitalized local variable. Two, actually.

Comment: You've tagged post with 3 languages - can you please clarify how this post relates to C++ or brainfuck? And how it is related to VS plugins? Please [edit] to remove unrelated tags or clarify how those tags apply to the question.

Comment: Which two variables?

Comment: `[ebp-4]` and `[ebp-8]`

Comment: What does `mov edi, v`  compile to?  It probably uses EBP, but you modify EBP inside your asm statement as if you were writing a `naked` function.  So you probably break access to named C++ local vars.  Use disassembly mode in the debugger to check.